# How to slideDown class in the same parent of the focused input

Tags: jquery, css, html, slide

I want to select the `.input-addition` class in the **same** `.field` class where the focused input is.

I tried something like the following but it does not work at all.

**HTML5**

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="email" id="emailConfirm" name="emailConfirm" maxlength="254" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="input-addition">↳ Re-enter your email to make sure it's correct.</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#signup input").focus(function() {
        $(this).closest('.input-addition').slideDown("fast").css('display', 'block');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    $(this).siblings('.input-addition')[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TvTP8/).

This approach slides *down* the sibling `.input-addition` if the `input` is focused, and slides it away when the `input` is blurred.

> How would I set it to slide up and down fast in your code?

Simply pass the `duration` to the method:

```
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e){
    $(this).siblings('.input-addition')[e.type === 'focus' ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']('fast');
});
```

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).
- [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Comment: How would I set it to slide up and down `fast` in your code?

Comment: Put the word slow, fast or a number in milliseconds in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

`.input-addition` is not a parent of your input, it's a sibling :

```
$(this).siblings('.input-addition').slideDown("fast");
//or
$(this).next('.input-addition').slideDown("fast");
```

I would use sibling since if you insert something between the input and the sapn, next will not work.

If you want a *change proof* code, use that :

```
$(this).closest('.field').find('.input-addition').slideDown("fast");
```